# Mule delay endpoint start time

Tags: jdbc, mule, endpoint

Is there an option available in Mule for specifying the jdbc polling time to begin (not the pollingFrequency). My scenario is, we are going to deploy the application in two nodes, so want to specify the start time for the polling to begin, so there will not be duplicate processing.

Comment: @DavidDossot : could you throw some light on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of playing with delay, I would use a [Quartz endpoint poller](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Quartz+Transport+Reference#QuartzTransportReference-EndpointPollingJob) with different Cron expressions for my 2 nodes (externally configured in a properties file). That way, the polling times will be strictly configured.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply !! Yes, this way we can..btw is it possible for specifying the jdbc polling time to begin polling at a given time ?

Comment: See "Example Cron Expressions" here: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06